# Outer Join Table in Oracle - Join separately by each date

Tags: database, oracle, join

Suppose I have some data and doing a query, I got something like this -

```
-----------------------------
trun(date) | location | sum |
-----------------------------
14-June-11 | B        | 5   |
-----------------------------
13-June-11 | B        | 5   |
-----------------------------
14-June-11 | C        | 5   |
-----------------------------
13-June-11 | C        | 5   |
-----------------------------

SELECT TRUNC(DATE_TIME),MIN(LOCATION) AS LOCATION, SUM(CREDIT) AS SUM FROM 
(SELECT * FROM TABLE A
WHERE
 A.DATE_TIME >= TO_DATE('13/JUN/2011','dd/mon/yyyy')
 AND A.DATE_TIME <= TO_DATE('15/JUN/2011','dd/mon/yyyy'))
GROUP BY TRUNC(DATE_TIME), LOCATION
```

There's another table B where there's a location list

```
----
A  |
----
B  |
----
C  |
----
```

I want something like this -

```
-----------------------------
trun(date) | location | sum |
-----------------------------
14-June-11 | A        | 0   |
-----------------------------
14-June-11 | B        | 5   |
-----------------------------
14-June-11 | C        | 5   |
-----------------------------
13-June-11 | A        | 0   |
-----------------------------
13-June-11 | B        | 5   |
-----------------------------
13-June-11 | C        | 5   |
-----------------------------
```

I tried to use a right join with the table B, but I can't create 2 separate records for 14-June-11 and 13-June-11. Any advice or help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to read `tablea` separately to get the distinct `date_time` values.  Instead, this is a job for the often overlooked **partitioned outer join**.

Here is your answer using that feature.  (The tables and inserts from William Robertson's answer will work to set this up).

```
select a.date_time
     , b.location
     , coalesce(a.asum,0) as asum
from  ( SELECT trunc(a.date_time) date_time, 
               a.location, 
               sum(a.credit) as asum 
        FROM tablea a 
        WHERE  a.date_time between date '2011-06-13' and date '2011-06-15' or a.date_time is null
        GROUP BY trunc(a.date_time), a.location ) a 
        -- This is the key part here...
        PARTITION BY (date_time)
right join tableb b on a.location = b.location
order by 1 desc, 2;
```

What that `PARTITION BY` keyword does is makes the outer join operate separately for each distinct value of `date_time`, creating null outer-join rows as needed for each one.

> ```
> +-----------+----------+------+
> | DATE_TIME | LOCATION | ASUM |
> +-----------+----------+------+
> | 14-JUN-11 | A        |    0 |
> | 14-JUN-11 | B        |    5 |
> | 14-JUN-11 | C        |    5 |
> | 13-JUN-11 | A        |    0 |
> | 13-JUN-11 | B        |    5 |
> | 13-JUN-11 | C        |    5 |
> +-----------+----------+------+
> ```

Comment: Wow I've been using Oracle databases half of my life and I've never seen this partition clause on joins. (In Oracle 11.2.0.2.0 it seems a bit flawed, though. I've produced an ORA-00600 by rewriting this query and I'm obviously not the only one encountering such problems: https://blog.duncanworthy.me/sql/ora-600-error-partitioned-join/)

Comment: I can't say I've used it extensively (the use case doesn't seem to come up that often), but it has always worked for me the few times that I needed it.  The query I posted above runs fine on Oracle 12.1.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
with dates as
     ( select distinct trunc(date_time) as date_time from tablea )
select trunc(d.date_time)
     , b.location
     , coalesce(sum(credit),0) as sum
from   dates d
       cross join tableb b
       left join tablea a
            on  a.location = b.location
            and trunc(a.date_time) = d.date_time
where  a.date_time between date '2011-06-13' and date '2011-06-15' or a.date_time is null
group by d.date_time, b.location
order by 1 desc, 2;
```

Test data:

```
create table tablea
( date_time date
, location varchar2(1)
, credit number(1,0) );

create table tableb(location varchar2(1));

insert into tablea values (date '2011-06-14' + dbms_random.value, 'B', 2);
insert into tablea values (date '2011-06-14' + dbms_random.value, 'B', 3);
insert into tablea values (date '2011-06-14' + dbms_random.value, 'C', 5);

insert into tablea values (date '2011-06-13' + dbms_random.value, 'B', 1);
insert into tablea values (date '2011-06-13' + dbms_random.value, 'B', 2);
insert into tablea values (date '2011-06-13' + dbms_random.value, 'B', 2);

insert into tablea values (date '2011-06-13' + dbms_random.value, 'C', 1);
insert into tablea values (date '2011-06-13' + dbms_random.value, 'C', 2);
insert into tablea values (date '2011-06-13' + dbms_random.value, 'C', 2);

insert into tableb values('A');
insert into tableb values('B');
insert into tableb values('C');
```